# Foreign Key Violation in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, data-modeling

I'm working on my portfolio project of UDACITY Data Engineer nanodegree, its about Data modeling with postgresql. I have multiple table but I have ran across an error in the start. I'm trying to insert the data but there is a foreign key violation and i can't understand what's wrong.

This is my python code

```
song_data_df = df[['song_id', 'title', 'artist_id', 'year', 'duration']]
song_data_values = song_data_df.values
first_record_df = song_data_values[0]
song_data = first_record_df.tolist()
song_data

cur.execute(song_table_insert, song_data)
conn.commit()
```

These are two tables insert queries.

```
song_table_insert = ("""
    INSERT INTO songs
        (
        song_id,
        title,
        artist_id,
        year,
        duration        
        )
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (song_id)
    DO NOTHING
""")

artist_table_insert = ("""
    INSERT INTO artists
        (
            artist_id,
            name,
            location,
            latitude,
            longitude
        )
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (artist_id)
    DO NOTHING;
""")
```

This is my create table query and upto my knowledge I do not find anything wrong in there but unable to proceed with my code

```
song_table_create = ("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs
        (
            song_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            artist_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            year INTEGER CHECK (year >= 0),
            duration DECIMAL NOT NULL
        );

""")

artist_table_create = ("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists
        (
            artist_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            location VARCHAR,
            latitude DECIMAL,
            longitude DECIMAL
        );

""")
```

```
ForeignKeyViolation                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cur.execute(song_table_insert, song_data)
      2 conn.commit()

ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "songs" violates foreign key constraint "songs_artist_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (artist_id)=(ARD7TVE1187B99BFB1) is not present in table "artists".
```

Comment: "DETAIL:  Key (artist_id)=(ARD7TVE1187B99BFB1) is not present in table 'artists'."

Insert the artist before you insert the artist's songs.